Python - How to read a CSV file with data starting on row 10 (skipping rows gives a NaN)
I have a CSV file where the first 8 rows explain the file and the data starts on row 10. I tried skipping the data first, however, it gave me errors with reading the file.
#Trying another way... Issue was because of the extra commas from the system data
with open('test.csv') as test:
    x = csv.DictReader(test)

# File Opening
data = pd.read_csv('Events.csv', encoding="cp1252", skiprows=[0,6]) # It uses 'cp1252'

Below is what the file looks like for better context:

When I open up the csv and either 1) delete the files or 2) re-save as an excel file, I am able to continue on with my python code.
I tried skipping rows but the data comes out 'NaN'.

How does this differ from your previous question ? Also, the image within your question appears to be that of a spreadsheet and not a CSV file

can you show what the dataframe looks like if you use pd.read_csv('Events.csv', encoding="cp1252", skiprows=10) ?

@SIGHUP The picture isn't the actual file but what the information looks like. I also opened the .csv file in excel to look at the data as I cannot open it using Python. And I changed how the question was phased because I thought it was an encoding situation. I still don't have a resolution to this problem.

@iBeMeltin    When I print(data.head()):
Unnamed: 0
0         NaN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3         NaN
4         NaN

it looks like you should be skipping 9 rows

@iBeMeltin I changed to (skiprows=[0.9]) and got this error: File parsers.pyx:838, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory()
File parsers.pyx:905, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()
File parsers.pyx:874, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()
File parsers.pyx:891, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._check_tokenize_status()
File parsers.pyx:2061, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 7, saw 2

it should be 8 actually. don't pass a list, pass a scalar value.

@MichelleBogush Showing an image of how Excel has processed the CSV file is utterly pointless. There may be content in the CSV that Excel ignores or otherwise parses in some "special" way. Show the CSV content. Also, what did you hope skiprows=[0.9] would achieve? Did you read the documentation?

Consider this input CSV, which has 6 lines at the top that aren't part of the data (5 lines with text, and another blank line):
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5

Col_1,Col_2,Col_3
r1_c1,r1_c2,r1_c3
r2_c1,r2_c2,r2_c3
r3_c1,r3_c2,r3_c3
r4_c1,r4_c2,r4_c3
r5_c1,r5_c2,r5_c3

We can use the base file object to iterate past the garbage lines by calling next(f) repeatedly, then hand the file object over the csv module's readers:
import csv

with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    for _ in range(6):
        line = next(f)
        print(f"discarded line: {repr(line)}")

    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)

When I run that, I see:
discarded line: 'line1\n'
discarded line: 'line2\n'
discarded line: 'line3\n'
discarded line: 'line4\n'
discarded line: 'line5\n'
discarded line: '\n'
{'Col_1': 'r1_c1', 'Col_2': 'r1_c2', 'Col_3': 'r1_c3'}
{'Col_1': 'r2_c1', 'Col_2': 'r2_c2', 'Col_3': 'r2_c3'}
{'Col_1': 'r3_c1', 'Col_2': 'r3_c2', 'Col_3': 'r3_c3'}
{'Col_1': 'r4_c1', 'Col_2': 'r4_c2', 'Col_3': 'r4_c3'}
{'Col_1': 'r5_c1', 'Col_2': 'r5_c2', 'Col_3': 'r5_c3'}

You might even be able to hand the file object over to Pandas after skipping the garbage lines, but I don't use Pandas so I cannot say for certain.

Why do that when pandas.read_csv() has a skiprows option?

@SIGHUP, OP showed they had tried with DictReader, so I based my answer on that. Also, OP indicated they had tried skip rows, but were having problems. I added  the last suggestion about Pandas because I thought it might be helpful to consider a mix of approaches.
